# Having trouble using .h files to export functions

Tags: c

I have a .c file which has code for functions, and a .h file that sets up the function prototypes so they can be accessed from other files, but they are in conflict.

Here is the error I get:

```
file.c:111: error: ‘Function’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
file.h:16: error: previous declaration of ‘Function’ was here
```

In file.c:

```
#include "file.h"
...

void *Function(const char *filename) {
    ...
}
```

In file.h:

```
typedef void (*Function)(const char *filename);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating typedef of a function pointer instead of a prototype. Your declaration says that variable of type `Function` is a pointer to a function returning nothing and accepting a `const char*`.

I think what you really want in the .h file is this:

```
void *Function(const char *filename);
```

Comment: does he not also need `extern` ?

Comment: @Alnitak: I'm not sure there. I didn't think function prototypes needed `extern`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Fred I checked - C FAQ says it's optional (http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx5b.html) but I always include it from force of habit...

Comment: @Alnitak: Thanks for checking. I'm sure it doesn't hurt anything. 8v)

Comment: Hello. That worked. I was using typedef last time because I looked at an example where the .h file used it and it worked. Any idea why they used the typedef like that?

Comment: @hut123: I'm sure it was using a function pointer for something. Hard to say without seeing the example.

Comment: A typedef like that is useful when you want to pass a function pointer to another function (as in `qsort`). This way you can write: `void another_function(Function function_pointer){ ... }`